# Script element block in head but don't block in body

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, block

I use cuzillion to build a [page](http://stevesouders.com/cuzillion/?c0=hj1hfff2_3_f&c1=bi1hfff2_0_f&c2=bi1hfff2_0_f&c3=bi1hfff2_0_f&c4=bi1hfff2_0_f&c5=bi1hfff2_0_f&t=1394437830460) with script element in head:

```
<head>
    <script></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
</body>
```

this script element load with 2 second delay, and need 3 second to execute. When I load this page in Chrome, the network show the net status:

[image]

Obviously load script block the parser for parse the images in body. The images have to load after the script have been loaded

(May be you mentioned there is an image loaded in advance. I think this is because the `webkit preloader` triggered).

However, when I [move the script into body](http://stevesouders.com/cuzillion/?c0=bi1hfff2_0_f&c1=bi1hfff2_0_f&c2=bj1hfff2_3_f&c3=bi1hfff2_0_f&c4=bi1hfff2_0_f&c5=bi1hfff2_0_f&t=1394437765037),

```
<body>
   <img/>
   <img/>
   <script></script>
   <img/>
   <img/>
</body>
```

it doesn't block the image load under it:

[image]

But why? Why the script block in head but not in body? What's the differences?

Comment: read this it might be helpful to you http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Answer (score 0):

If you are sourcing an external script, you can use the async attribute to tell the browser to fetch it in parallel.